# How do I get the URL of a rails app...not the current controller URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a partial which gets loaded on a few different views. The partial contains a button which connects to an update method in one of my controllers. After the button gets pressed, I want the action to occur and then redirect back to wherever the current user is. However, when I use things like request.path, it always redirects back to the specific model that the button connects with. How do I do a true redirect back to the current page the user is on, regardless of where the button points to?

Comment: add this:  <a href="javascript:history.back();">back</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller that is being called by the new, edit, or destroy action you will want to change the @controller in the action (create, update, destroy) that is being called.

Below, you can see where when a users creates a new answer, it will redirect them to the previous page.

```
  # POST /answers
  # POST /answers.json
  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(params[:answer])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @answer.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: :back, status: :created, location: @answer }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to :back, alert: 'Error Posting Answer.' }
        format.json { render json: @answer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```